# Pandas run function only on subset of whole Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have Dataframe, which has 200 values, prices for products. I want to run some operation on this dataframe, like calculate average price for last 10 prices.
The way i understand it, right now pandas will go through every single row and calculate average for each row. Ie first 9 rows will be Nan, then from 10-200, it would calculate average for each row.

My issue is that i need to do a lot of these calculations and performance is an issue. For that reason, i would want to run the average only on say on last 10 values (dont need more) from all values, while i want to keep those values in the dataframe. Ie i dont want to get rid of those values or create new Dataframe.
I just essentially want to do calculation on less data, so it is faster.

Is something like that possible? Hopefully the question is clear.

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe with expected values (not 200 rows, you can share 10 rows). data not pics

Comment: What's wrong with choosing the last 10 rows `df.iloc[-10:]` and applying the function to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off [Chicodelarose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68493038/2714651), you can achieve this in a more "`pandas`-like" syntax.

Defining your `df` as follows, we get 200 prices up to within `[0, 1000)`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(200) * 1000.).round(decimals=2), columns=["price"])
```

The bit you're looking for, though, would the following:

```py
def add10(n: float) -> float:
    """An exceptionally simple function to demonstrate you can set 
    values, too.
    """
    return n + 10

df["price"].iloc[-12:] = df["price"].iloc[-12:].apply(add10)
```

Of course, you can also use these selections to return something else without setting values, too.

```py
>>> df["price"].iloc[-12:].mean().round(decimals=2)
309.63  # this will, of course, be different as we're using random numbers
```

The primary justification for this approach lies in the use of `pandas` tooling. Say you want to operate over a subset of your data with multiple columns, you simply need to adjust your `.apply(...)` to contain an `axis` parameter, as follows: `.apply(fn, axis=1)`.

This becomes much more readable the longer you spend in `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a dataframe like the following:

```
      Price
0    197.45
1     59.30
2    131.63
3    127.22
4     35.22
..      ...
195   73.05
196   47.73
197  107.58
198  162.31
199  195.02

[200 rows x 1 columns]
```

Call the following to obtain the mean over the last n rows of the dataframe:

```
def mean_over_n_last_rows(df, n, colname):
    return df.iloc[-n:][colname].mean().round(decimals=2)

print(mean_over_n_last_rows(df, 2, "Price"))
```

Output:

```
178.67
```